# Need to Add Upload file field in add customer in magento backend

Tags: magento

I need to pull the file in magento db, as i am using the below code in Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php

```
$fieldset->addField('customer_entity.Upload_Logo_Cst', 'File', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Upload Logo'),
            'name'  => 'uploadlogo',
            'id'    => 'uploadlogo',

        ));
```

Its coming in the backend fine but also need to uploaded file should come in db (have created a field also name Upload_Logo_Cst in customer_entity table)--Still Fails--Any idea, please share with me.

I am waiting from last one day. any Comments would be appreciate

thank you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6